# Symmetric Roles of the two problem solutions in RINS

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation, heuristics, mathematical-programming

Currently, I am reading the paper "Exploring relaxation induced neighborhood to improve MIP solutions" by Danna et.al. from 2004 and they are talking about a symmetric role of incumbent and the relaxed solution. Which I understood as following:

An incumbent of poor quality can be improved because the respective relaxation is leading into a good direction. And vice versa, a loose relaxation can be compensated by an incumbent of good quality.

How does it work? Can it not happen that it still continues into a completely bad direction?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Do you by any chance have a link to a freely available PDF of the paper?

Comment: Can you see the full text here: http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/696/art%253A10.1007%252Fs10107-004-0518-7.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs10107-004-0518-7&token2=exp=1456775345~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F696%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs10107-004-0518-7.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs10107-004-0518-7*~hmac=7b18027492f15466ea8d93356d3c7d034b635e29959bee1871bb302bef8d96ab ?